# sequence defined recursively as $a_0 = 0$, $a_k = k + a_{k - 1}$ for each integer $k \geq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

Should I use $a_n = a_1 + d(n−1)$ to find the explicit formula...?  And how to prove it is correct？ Thank you!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The sequence is $0, 1, 3, 6,\ldots$, where we see that the differences... differ. So it's clear that $a_1 + d(n-1)$ (or rather $a_0 + dn$, which looks a lot nicer) won't do.

Comment: Note that $a_{n} - a_{n-1} = n$

Comment: Then write out $a_{n-1}$ all the way to $a_{0}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: it is $$a_k=\frac{1}{2}k(k+1)+C$$ compute $C$!

Answer (score 0):

$$a_0=0;\\a_1=1+a_0=1+0=1;\\a_2=2+a_1=2+1=3;\\a_3=3+a_2=3+3=6;\\a_4=4+a_3=4+6=10;
\\a_5=5+a_4=5+10=15;\\a_6=6+a_5=6+15=21;$$
Do you notice a pattern? If you were asked to compute, say, $a_11$ without computing the other $a_i$'s, how would you do it?

After you have figured that out, using that the sum of an arithmetic series will be useful: $$b,b+d,...,b+kd=\frac {k+1}2(b+(b+kd))$$